# Google App Engine Error importing Openai Python library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, openai-api

I want to deploy a flask app to google app engine. The app deploys but when i import the openai library an error server error occurs.

If I comment out the import of openai the html site is displayed but I need the library for the whole code to work properly. I installed openai in the instance directly with pip but this does not changened anything.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openai 
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, 
cosine_similarity
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
    def search():
        openai.api_key = 'key'

        embedding_model = 'text-embedding-ada-002'
        embedding_encoding = 'c11ok_base'
        max_tokens = 8000

        datafile_path = './data/quotes_with_embeddings.csv' 

        df = pd.read_csv(datafile_path)
        df["embedding"] = df.embedding.apply(eval).apply(np.array)
        search_query = request.form.get('search_query')
        api_response = get_embedding(search_query, engine='text-embedding-ada-002')

        df["similarity"] = df.embedding.apply(lambda x: 
        cosine_similarity(x, api_response))

        results = (
            df.sort_values("similarity", ascending=False)
       .head(3)
       )


        return render_template('search.html', quote0 = str(results.iloc[0,1]),author0 = str(results.iloc[0,2]), quote1 = str(results.iloc[1,1]), author1 = str(results.iloc[1,2]), quote2 = str(results.iloc[2,1]), author2 = str(results.iloc[2,2]))
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python39

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static


- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.1.1
cycler==0.11.0
flask==2.3.3
fonttools==4.42.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
importlib-resources==6.1.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.8.0
multidict==6.0.4
numpy==1.26.0
openai==0.28.0
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.1.1
Pillow==10.0.1
plotly==5.17.0
pyparsing==3.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
regex==2023.8.8
requests==2.31.0
scikit-learn==1.3.1
scipy==1.11.2
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0
tenacity==8.2.3
threadpoolctl==3.2.0
tiktoken==0.5.1
tqdm==4.66.1
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.5
werkzeug==2.3.7
yarl==1.9.2
zipp==3.17.0
```

I get this error log with the command gcloud app logs tail -s default

```
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)  
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2023-09-26 16:26:38 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:38 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2023-09-26 16:26:39 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:39 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
2023-09-26 16:26:44 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-26 16:26:45 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:45 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2023-09-26 16:26:45 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:45 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
2023-09-26 16:26:45 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:45 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
2023-09-26 16:26:45 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:45 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
2023-09-26 16:26:46 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:26:46 +0000] [11] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2023-09-26 16:28:41 default[20230926t182237]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)  
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2023-09-26 16:28:42 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:42 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
2023-09-26 16:28:47 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:47 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-26 16:28:48 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:48 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
2023-09-26 16:28:48 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:48 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
2023-09-26 16:28:48 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:48 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
2023-09-26 16:28:48 default[20230926t182237]  [2023-09-26 16:28:48 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2023-09-26 16:36:48 default[20230926t181958]  [2023-09-26 16:36:48 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-26 16:36:48 default[20230926t181958]  [2023-09-26 16:36:48 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2023-09-26 16:36:49 default[20230926t181958]  [2023-09-26 16:36:49 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
2023-09-26 16:36:49 default[20230926t181958]  [2023-09-26 16:36:49 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
2023-09-26 16:36:49 default[20230926t181958]  [2023-09-26 16:36:49 +0000] [21] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21)
2023-09-26 16:44:19 default[20230926t184232]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)  
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2023-09-26 16:44:20 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:20 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
2023-09-26 16:44:27 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:44:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-26 16:46:31 default[20230926t184232]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2023-09-26 16:46:32 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:46:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-09-26 16:46:32 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:46:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)  
2023-09-26 16:46:32 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:46:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2023-09-26 16:46:32 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:46:32 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2023-09-26 16:46:32 default[20230926t184232]  [2023-09-26 16:46:32 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
```

Comment: Check your logs and tell us what error you see there

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i added the logs. I can't identify any error due to the openai module